# Using 'as'/coerce method from another package in my package

Tags: r

I'm writing an R package, and want to internally use an 'as' function from another package to coerce an an object. But I can't figure out how to import it in the package (with either importFrom or ::) like you would an normally exported function.

How can I import a particular flavour of the 'as' method into my package from another package? Or all 'as' methods from another package?

Specifically: The 'contrast_each_group_to_the_rest' function in my package (celaref) that uses that will only work if you call library(MAST) alongside library(celaref).

The 'as' method I want it to use shows up in  `showMethods("coerce")` as `from="SingleCellExperiment", to="SingleCellAssay"`, when I import the 'MAST' package.

E.g. using demo data

```
library(celaref)              # my package, uses MAST internally
library(SingleCellExperiment) # a dependancy
# library(MAST)               # Uncomment this and it works
contrast_each_group_to_the_rest(demo_ref_se, num_cores=1)
```

Yeilds error:

```
Error in as(sca, "SingleCellAssay") : 
  no method or default for coercing “SingleCellExperiment” to “SingleCellAssay”
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: NAMESPACE is here:https://github.com/MonashBioinformaticsPlatform/celaref/blob/master/NAMESPACE   and DESCRIPTION is here: https://github.com/MonashBioinformaticsPlatform/celaref/blob/master/DESCRIPTION

Comment: You might try adding `importFrom("methods", as)` - https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L24 this makes me think that MAST may need to add that to _their_ NAMESPACE.

Comment: Thanks Neal - that has fixed it.  Adding `#' @importFrom "methods" as` to my function header doco for roxygen2 to render as `importFrom("methods",as)` in the NAMESPACE does the job. Just had to remember to include the quotes around methods, as it doesn't seem to work without, unsure why.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Neal Fultz:

> You might try adding importFrom("methods", as) - github.com/cran/Matrix
>   /blob/master/NAMESPACE#L24 this makes me think that MAST may need to add that 
>   to their NAMESPACE.

This works:

`#' @importFrom "methods" as` in function header

or

`importFrom("methods",as)` in NAMESPACE

**CORRECTION - actually, this doesn't seem to work as I thought it did. Any further tips appreciated.**

Fix - importing MAST in the function header (oops) and using a weird looking 'as' format that I don't quite understand. (Probably dependent on the actual (very similar) data objects in these packages)

```
#' @import SummarizedExperiment
#' @import MAST
```

```
sca <- new("SingleCellAssay")
as(sca, "SingleCellExperiment") <- sce.in
```